# strategy/pattern to create working chain

Tags: design-patterns

I need a pattern/strategie to solve my problem. Do you know some book or something where I could read it up?

My problem (all theory):
I have some kind of game and there I have 2 NPCs. They are workers, that have to repair some stuff. For that they need different materials depending on the error. When an error comes in I calculate which NPC would be the fastest. To do that I calculate for each NPC every move the NPC would have to take (walking, waiting,...). Workers could also be occupied for some time with another task, so I also have to consider that in my calculation.

Now my thoght was I could use the same code (with little modification) to let the NPC walk after I decided which one would fit best for that task, but in my eyes that's a huge redundancy and I would like to avoid that. Also I would have to stop some tasks midway and let the NPC go work somewhere else. Don't think that would be easy to handle this way.

So my second thought was to create something like a working chain. In my time calculation I already decide what the NPC would have to to/where to walk. So I could, at this point, add something that writes that action into a list. A loop would execute the actions and it would be easy to stop at any point. (Of course I would have two lists after each calculation, one for each NPC. But only the fastest would be used.)

If there is a pattern or something alike someone came up with, I would appreciate if you could point me to that source.

Or is there even a better way to solve that?

-Regards

EDIT:

The time is calculated in different ways, e.g. when the worker has to walk somewhere, this time (distance/speed) is calculated. For different waiting times there are different values for different occasions. In the end the sum of all those times is returned. But the whole method is more than just adding up different times. To get the times right, it looks for the best routes depending on the position of the worker. So the actions order can be different each time ... The actions itself are methods, something like walk(start, dest) or wait(seconds).
So I thought, when the method already looks for the best order of actions to get the calculation right, it could also store that in some kind of list to use this in the actual animation ... I would store the actions in an array where the entries are: a number that stands for the method to use and the rest would be the parameters

Comment: That's just optimization really... I'm not sure if there is a pattern for this... perhaps it's called the efficiency pattern? ;) It would help if you could give more insights on how the actions are represented and executed and how you estimate their time? To me the process that decides which actions have to be taken shouldn't be the one that estimates the time or that violates the SRP.

Comment: The time is calculated in different ways, e.g. when the worker has to walk somewhere, this time (distance/speed) is calculated. For different waiting times there are different values for different occasions. In the end the sum of all those times is returned. But the whole method is more than just adding up different times. To get the times right, it looks for the best routes depending on the position of the worker. So the actions order can be different each time ... The actions itself are methods, something like walk(start, dest) or wait(seconds)...(continued next comment)

Comment: (continue of last comment) ... So I thought, when the method already looks for the best order of actions to get the calculation right, it could also store that in some kind of list to use this in the actual animation ... I would store the actions in an array where the entries are: a number that stands for the method to use and the rest would be the parameters.

Comment: This is really what you should be doing because of the single responsability principle. To determine which actions have to take place is one responsability that should not be coupled to time calculation or action execution. I'd definitely start by creating a list of unweighted actions first for each worker.